# Can't label closure arguments in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Completion handlers is a pretty commonly used designed pattern in iOS.

Consider this common scenario:

I need to fetch a JSON string. If it fails, I will return an error. I setup my fetch call like this:

```
func getData(completionHandler: @escaping (_ jsonString: String?, _ error:     String?) -> Void) {

}
```

And then calling this function we'd get this:

```
getData { (<#String?#>, <#String?#>) in
    <#code#>
}
```

`//<#stuff#> represents an auto-complete placeholder in xcode`

So we have two arguments that contain the data, and the error. Both optional. 
Which one is which? Swift 3 supposedly focused on creating clarity AT POINT OF USE, but right here... I have no idea which one is which. Anyone who is unfamiliar with this code will end up making mistakes

So I try to explicitly label the arguments either by removing `'_'` or by adding labels like this:

```
func getData(completionHandler: @escaping (json jsonString: String?, theError error:     String?) -> Void) {

}
```

However, I get these errors:
`Function types cannot have argument label 'json' use '_' instead`
`Function types cannot have argument label 'theError' use '_' instead`

What I want to be able to do is name these arguments explicitly, or even at least view their label in autocomplete when I'm setting up the call.

So essentially,
when I type out the call I'd get this:

```
getData { (<#jsonString: String?#>, <#theError: String?#>) in
    <#code#>
}
```

or

```
getData { (jsonString, theError) in
    <#code#>
}
```

I can't think of doing this without creating a `typealias` for every closure type, which seems ridiculous

Is there a way to do what I'm wanting?
Was this scenario considered when this feature was killed?

This seems to go against all the wisdom laid out by: https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Comment: you would only know which one was which if you went to the function declaration, which definitely goes against the Swift 3 guidelines, clarity at use

Comment: Why is your returned error of type `String?`? If you made it an error type, your completion handler would pretty clear.

Comment: Swift API Design guidelines: `To restore clarity, precede each weakly typed parameter with a noun describing its role`

Comment: It's an example, it could be any number of arguments, error was just an example.  Are you saying the best way describe a weakly typed property is by documentation or by using a different type with a more descriptive name?

Comment: The phrase `@escaping (_ jsonString: String?, _ error: String?) -> Void)`, which compiles as you rightly say, is self-documenting. The programmer will see it when doing code completion. No more is needed. You've solved the problem correctly. There's no more to do.

Comment: Well here's the reasoning for the change https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md

Comment: @YichenBman I certainly do agree with you that the situation is far from ideal at the moment – in fact the Swift team feel the same way and are looking to "restore the expressive capability of closures with parameter labels" with an additive post Swift 3 update ([see here for the details](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2016-July/000233.html)). From what it looks like this will re-introduce closure parameter names as part of the declaration name, rather than the type. Although whether this'll improve the auto-completion of closure expressions, I'm not too sure.

Comment: @Hamish that is exactly what I like to hear. I just couldn't believe that I was the only one that felt this way

Comment: @matt I might be overlooking something, but as far as I can see, the "cosmetic" parameter labels never show up in code completion. When typing in the method, the compiler shows me `getData(completionHandler: (String?, String?) -> Void)` – when hitting enter again to autocomplete the closure expression, it gives me `getData {(String?, String?) in code}`.

Comment: @Hamish Well darn. But in any case this change in Swift 3 is well documented, however much we may regret it. (There is a _lot_ about Swift 3 that I don't like, but the train has left the station.)